# LESS: darken() on current color

Tags: less

I want to call LESS's `darken()` function on whatever the current color is (I don't have the current color in any variable). Is that possible?

Comment: In short, no, it's not. Just because Less also has no idea what the current color is.

Comment: Just in case, there're a few tricks for "current color" (assuming any arbitrary "current"s including those inherited by DOM) at least when it comes to `background` colors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591445, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878924; but in general it's recommended to use variables.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, LESS as a preprocessor can never support this, can it?

Comment: it could be possible if running less in the server on request. You can run js in less

Comment: @Santiago Rebella, I'd like to see how you imagine this (As Borek guessed in fact this is impossible with a CSS-preprocessor at all just by design. Assuming we define "current color" as something that depends on HTML DOM structure or similar stuff).

Comment: @seven-phases-max if you compile the less on the server as per request, then you could get a js variable, like bodyColor, then assign it to a less variable, and then darken that color. Is not recommended yet to run it on server side runtime, but is not impossible

Answer (score -1):

as per seven-phases-max request; in your node backend let say express

```
var less = require('less'); //also the body parser, express, etc
```

....

from your page you make an asynchronous request with the actual color of your page, just grabbing it with js and making the request. then in express:

```
app.post('/whateveryourroute', function(req, res) {
    var colorFromReq = req.body.color;
    less.render('.class { color: darken(`colorFromReq`, 20%) }', function (e, css) {
      res.header("Content-type", "text/css");
      res.send(css);
    });
});
```

Something like that would be, didnt test it, but is possible.

Comment: I see. Though I can't see how this can be possibly better than just setting the corresponding value directly by the script with *no* server or Less involved. That's why I still will use "impossible" for that case simply because not every "theoretically possible" stuff make sense in practice. (In this particular case this trick spoils the very idea of a CSS-preprocessor). Either way thanks for the answer :)

Comment: the server would be involved because in this way you dont need to know the color value at all, just get it from the element, send the post request and receive it darkened. I think is the only way you could do it without having to know that value. you are welcome ;)

Comment: >I think is the only way you could do it - Is it? [Codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/wFnqD). That's the point, there's no reason to involve server or Less at all if you're fine to manipulate your styles with a script.

Comment: @seven-phases-max but i thought the question was I want to call LESS's darken() function, I have no idea how would you do that without involving LESS, in your example you do exactly what i said, but without using the only tool requested in the question, in fact you said was impossible