# Change the background color with less recursively

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am rendering one a form with fields and groups with bootstrap panels recursively, so there are panels within panels. How do I recursively'll never know the maximum depth that can have the panels, I want to do is go by the lighter color of the header panel. Preserving the father the primary color of bootstrap.
My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Less</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.less" />


    </head>
    <body style="padding-top:20px;">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div id="father" class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 1</h3></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        Panel content 1
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 2</h3></div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel content 2

                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 2</h3></div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                        Panel content 3

                                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Panel title n</h3></div>
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                Panel content n

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="assets/vendors/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendors/less-1.7.5.min.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

My less code:

```
@color: #428bca;

.panel-heading {
  background-color: lighten(@color, 10%) !important;
}
```

I do not know how to make it clearer fence by recursively taking the color of the parent panel.

Comment: Could you please clarify more on the question (or) maybe add some sample version of the CSS (not the Less code) you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make the header of each panel that is inside another panel clearer, I supono that I have to use less to make a recursive function that takes the background color of the father and applies the function lighten the background color of the child.

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/kvilb) what you need? This is adapted from an earlier answer on SO which I can't seem to find now.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878924/how-to-override-a-less-mixin-variable-based-on-a-parents-variable/24880702#24880702)  is the other answer that I was referring to (and there are a couple more other answers from ScottS and seven-phases-max linked within it too)

Comment: Yes, what I want is the first example, but only the background color of the header, try changing the class panel panel-heading does not work.

Comment: What should happen to be panel-body? Should all panel-body stay the same color? If yes, I don't think it might be possible.

Comment: I think you're not understanding me. The first example was right, but do not want the div with the class "panel". I want to change color of divs with the class "panel-heading"

Comment: Well, as mentioned in the linked Q&As, you *can't* "take the background color of the father and apply the function lighten the background color of the child" in CSS (and thus in Less). So if I understand the desired coloring correctly probably something like [**this**](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/pyBdb?editors=110) is the method you can go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Q is a sort of duplicate of:

- [Lighten parent's (unknown) background-color in child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21591445/2712740)
- [How to override a LESS mixin variable based on a parent's variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24878924/2712740)

(see there for more details on why you can't reuse parent property values in child rulesets).
Fortunately there's still a pure Less/CSS solution for your particular example, hence I guess it's OK to provide a dedicated answer. You just need to pregenerate styles for a reasonable amount of nested panels. And since you're using explicitly specified color value the code becomes as simple as just:

```
.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
    .lighten-nested-panels(#428bca, 5);
}

.lighten-nested-panels(@color, @max-nesting-level, @fade: 10%) {
    .-; .-(@i: 0) when (@i < @max-nesting-level) {
        background-color: lighten(@color, (@fade * @i));
        .panel & {.-((@i + 1))}
    }
}
```

with resulting CSS:

```
                     .panel-primary > .panel-heading {background-color: #428bca}
              .panel .panel-primary > .panel-heading {background-color: #6aa3d5}
       .panel .panel .panel-primary > .panel-heading {background-color: #92bce0}
.panel .panel .panel .panel-primary > .panel-heading {background-color: #b9d4ec}
// etc.
```

Complete [**codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/pyBdb?editors=110).

Additionally it is also possible to modify this method to work for "unknown" `.panel-heading` colors by darkening/lightening via either `:before/:after` layer (as in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21592774/2712740)) or a `gradient` overlay (as in [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880702/2712740)).

Comment: It has worked well, I wanted to recursively without limit, but I doubt that the level Depth exceeding 5 or 6 panels. Thank you very much.