# Is it possible in LessCSS to read a given css property on an element?

Tags: css, less

I want to take the defined color (from another rule) and pass it to a mixin. Something effectively like this:

```
.btn-default {
    background: red;
}


.btn-green {
    background: green;
}

.btn-blue {
    background: blue;
}

// get inherited ('red', 'blue', or 'green') value here somehow
.btn-special {
    @bg-color: ??
    .darken(@bg-color, 20%);
}
```

The catch here is inside the `.btn-special` I don't know what the color is, it is set somewhere else...and could be changed based on what classes the button has applied to it.

I want `.btn-special` to pickup whatever the defined `background-color` is and pass its value to the `.darken()` mixin.

Is this possible?

The markup would be something like this:

```
<button class="btn-default btn-special"></button>
<button class="btn-green btn-special"></button>
<button class="btn-blue btn-special"></button>
```

Comment: Well, less is just a CSS preprocessor, so I doubt it can do something like this if it is not possible in CSS. I have looked into the attr() CSS [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) but it is very experimental, only works with the content attribute, and does not have a lot of support.

Comment: In css I would just do `inherit`, but I want to set it as a variable.

Comment: If all that the `darken` function does is to darken the background color, then you can do something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xKfhF). This is adapted from the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591445/lighten-parents-unknown-background-color-in-child).

Answer (score -1):

It's causes duplicated code but probably something like:

```
.btn-default {
    background: red;
    &.btn-special {
        background: .darken(red, 20%);
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: The question is specific to not knowing the color in this context.